# How to get the name of a variable as a string?

Tags: python

I'm writing a function to draw plots of dataframes and I would like to name the plots according to the name of the dataframe passed to the function. The first line of the plotter function is:

```
def plotter(data):
```

Say the data frame to be passed is `df1`, I'm wondering how could I get the string `'df1'` when calling `plotter(data=df1)`?

Comment: You can't, as only the reference is stored in `df1` and in the context of the `plotter` function the dataframe is called `data`.

Comment: You generally cannot; things do not have names, names have things. You can inspect the source code or stack, but there is no guarantee you will find a name there. For example, what would you expect the code to do when the function is called as ``plotter(**kws)`` or ``plotter(df_factory())``?

Comment: What you could do is to deliver the name alongside the dataframe itself, but this would mean to extend the signature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
from varname import nameof

def plotter(data, name_df):
  # name_df is a string which is is "df1", then you can add to the plot

plotter(df1, nameof(df1))
```

Comment: In that case why not just `plotter(df1, 'df1')`?

Comment: @Tomerikoo yeah... I don't really know  how he is getting  the  name of the dataframe

Comment: *"Say the data frame to be passed is `df1`, I'm wondering how could I get the string `'df1'`"* - they simply want the name of the variable...